# How can I create a recommended project in the root directory?

Tags: 8, composer

My server consists only one Drupal site and therefore I would like to install it directly under `D:\home\site\wwwroot`

However this seems impossible as the new command `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:~8.8.0 mysite` requires some sort of a folder name like 'mysite'.

All I want is Drupal composer.json stuff to be installed in `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and 'web' folder to be installed in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\web`

Is this possible at all?

Comment: If wwwroot is empty you can simply `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project .` from inside it. The `.` says: current directory.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I cannot mark it as the answer as it is just a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wwwroot is empty you can simply run the following command from inside this directory.

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project .
```

The `.` at the end says: current directory.

Answer (score 0):

In some shared hosting platforms, you cannot change the root folder.

You have an optional "drupal/legacy-project" option that creates the legacy folder organization.

“composer create-project drupal/legacy-project wwwroot”

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/starting-a-site-using-drupal-composer-project-templates

I have some websites on gandi.net (fr) shared hosting and it defaults the root folder to "subdomain.domain.tld/htdocs".

- I run the "drupal/recommended-project" composer command
- Rename the “web” folder to “htdocs”
- Edit the composer.json file to replace “web/” by “htdocs/”
- Run “composer update”

And voilá.

In the end, the “subdomain.domain.tld” folder looks like this:

- config/sync/ (created manually, outside of the Drupal installation directory, defined in settings.php)
- htdocs/
- private/ (created manually, outside of the Drupal installation directory, defined in settings.php)
- vendor/
- composer.json
- composer.lock

Edit: If you are unable to run the composer command in your shared hosting, do it locally on a LAMP (or Acquia Dev Desktop) and upload the compressed archive to your host.